# Anjuta runtime crash (Command line `dbus-launch -- autolaunch = --binary-syntax --close-stderr')

Tags: eclipse, unix, ubuntu, anjuta

I've recently installed anjuta and eclipse(ubuntu 12.04) and both crash upon execution.

Anjuta throws this warning:

```
 ** (anjuta:10578): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch            
 --autolaunch=ffab43442e6b810b3d0603ea00000009 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited       
 with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
```

Eclipse throws:

```
 (eclipse:10587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
 (eclipse:10587): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion   
 `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
 ** (eclipse:10587): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch   
 --autolaunch=ffab43442e6b810b3d0603ea00000009 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited 
 with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
 (eclipse:10587): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion    
 `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
 (eclipse:10587): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
 a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
 ...
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I set the screen for a GtkWindow?

Comment: are you running this on a remote computer?

Comment: No. I've recently installed ubuntu 12.04 and this shows up every time I try to open an application which uses X-windows. All text based editors/tools work properly.

Comment: It seems to me you don't have a dbus session launched.

Comment: Hmm...it appears that a dbus session cannot be launched(at least with those parameters).

Comment: See this comment https://sqt.ait.ac.at/software/issues/310#note-2 about your error "error: X11 initialization failed" .